# Are both of these ways correct to do beta reduction?

Tags: lambda-calculus

First way: (λz.(λx.x) z) -> (x)[x->z] -> (λz.z)
Second way: (λz.(λx.x) z) -> (λx.x)[z->z] -> (λx.x)

Any lambda calculus online calculator I'm using only provides the first way as a solution, whatever strategy I set on it, and I can't seem to figure out why the second way is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

The first way is correct as a beta-reduction. The second result is correct as an eta-reduction, although there's no substitution involved. Eta-reduction works as follows:

\x.ex -> e

Assuming x is not free in e. Note that (\x.ex)y = ey so (\x.ex) behaves the same as e, which is why eta-reduction works.